# shieldUI build chart images in java backend

Tags: charts, wicket, data-visualization, shieldui

I'm using shieldUi library for building charts in a web page.

I was wondering about creating charts in a Java backend and save them as images (or use them when creating a pdf using FOP).

Is shieldUi (and its integration with apache wicket) suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There are [integration Apache Wicket with ShieldUI](https://github.com/shieldui/wicket-shieldui).
Maybe it will help you!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I was able to deploy shieldUI demo  application. Now my problem is to save a page render as a pdf. Any suggestion? I'm trying with FOP, but it seems that html -> fo conversion misses charts infos.

Comment: Laura, I think it's yet another question :) Ask it if you haven't found solution.